# Moq + Unit Testing -- How can I pass an Action to my class to test if that Action gets invoked?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, action, moq, invoke

Basically, I have a method on my class that invokes an `Action<T>` if certain conditions are met. How can I unit test to ensure that the action is invoked?

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private IDBService _dbService;

    private Action<T> _action;

    public MyClass(IDBService dbService, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (dbService == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dbService");
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        _dbService = dbService;
        _action = action;
    }

    public void CallActionIfPossible(T param)
    {
        if (_dbService.IsTopUser)
            action(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your current code so we can craft a response?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the basic idea is that the `Action<T>` produces some state change somewhere (if it doesn't, what's the point?). So, unit test that the expected state change occurs when the conditions hold, and that the expected state change doesn't occur when the conditions do not hold.

Of course, ideally, you mock the `Action<T>` so that the state testing is super easy. You do not need Moq or any other mocking framework for this:

```
bool actionWasInvoked = false;
Action<Foo> action = foo => actionWasInvoked = true;
Bar<Foo> bar = new Bar<Foo>();
// set up conditions that should guarantee action is invoked
bar.M(action);
Assert.IsTrue(actionWasInvoked);
```

and

```
bool actionWasInvoked = false;
Action<Foo> action = foo => actionWasInvoked = true;
Bar<Foo> bar = new Bar<Foo>();
// set up conditions that should guarantee action is NOT invoked
bar.M(action);
Assert.IsFalse(actionWasInvoked);
```

Of course, I don't know your exact setup. Maybe you pass in `action` on construction of `Bar`, or maybe you have some other way of setting the action. But the idea should be clear.

Answer (score 4):

Jason's answer is good, but one caveat that is often overlooked is that you will often need to test for a certain number of invocations (e.g. not only was it called, but it was called exactly once). So I often do something like this:

```
var callCount = 0;
Action<Foo> action = _ => callCount++;
Bar<Foo> bar = new Bar<Foo>();
// set up conditions that should guarantee action is invoked
bar.M(action);
Assert.That(callCount, Is.EqualTo(1));
```

Comment: +1 I like the idea behind this (ensure it has the required amount of calls).